# How to check for multiple well formed XMLs inside a folder using xmllint

Tags: xml, shell

I have a folder which contains multiple xml files.
I want to make sure all the XMLs are well formed before passing the file to destination.
Currently I can validate single XML using xmllint by creating a shell script and then writing below script:

```
xmlfile=ValidXML.xml
xmllint --format "${xmlfile}"
```

But how can I achieve the same result if I have x number of XMLs in the folder.

Comment: try with find <folder> -name "*.xml" -exec xmllint --format {} \;

Comment: Don't you mean `--valid` instead of `--format`?

Comment: I don't have a Schema to match it against. I just want to check if XML is correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xmllint can process more than one file at once and so you can do:

```
xmllint ..... *.xml
```